# when the ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock function is trigger in ios

Tags: ios, image, video, alassetslibrary, alasset

In my app i want to get the image and video from particular album.so i use ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock function for get the images and video from the particular Album.here i store the asset value in a nsmutablearray,i get that array values on viewdidLoad, but in viewdidload the array value is null.So when ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock is trigger.
Below is my code help me..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
if (self.assetLibrary == nil) {
        _assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    }
    if (self.groups == nil) {
        _groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else {
        [self.groups removeAllObjects];
    }
[self loadAssetImages];
}
-(void)loadAssetImages{

    NSLog(@"Load  asset Image ");
    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Albums Available"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    };

    ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock listGroupBlock = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Block");
        if (group == nil)
        {
            return;
        }
        if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:@"FlipDemo"]) {
            [self.groups addObject:group];
            [self loadImages];
            return ;
        }
        if (stop) {
            return;
        }
    };

    NSLog(@"Block Out");
    [self.assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                           usingBlock: listGroupBlock
                         failureBlock:failureBlock];
}


-(void)loadImages{
     NSLog(@"Load Image000");
    ALAssetsGroup *assetGroup;
    for (assetGroup in self.groups)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<[self.groups count]; i++)
        {
           [ assetGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
            {
                if (result) {
                    if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo])
                    {
                        [videoOnly addObject:result];

                    }
                    else if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto])
                    {
                        [imgOnly addObject:result];
//                     NSLog(@"Photo");
                    }
                }
            }
            ];        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is asynchronous. You can find the function detail in help document:

> help document

- (void)enumerateGroupsWithTypes:(ALAssetsGroupType)types
                    usingBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock)enumerationBlock
                  failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock

This method is asynchronous. When groups are enumerated, the user may be asked to confirm the application's access to the data; the method, though, returns immediately. You should perform whatever work you want with the assets in enumerationBlock.

> end of help document

So, according your code, you can't get anything in your main thread. Because iOS get assets in another thread.

You can set a key-value observation to make main thread waiting for this asynchronous function.

1) set a property, for example: handleOverFindFlag
2) before execute the function: set handleOverFindFlag=NO
3) add Observer

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"handleOverFindFlag" options:0 context:NULL];
```

4) set observing function:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:

    (NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
    {
      if([keyPath isEqualToString:@""])
      {
         //handle your findings
      }
    }
```

5) after doing this

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"handleOverFindFlag"];
```

You can find detail about Key-Value coding in help document.